# Face data set with ca. 100-1000 images on each individual

Tags: data-request, images, faces

I'm looking for a data set that has a larger number of images associated with 1 individual in a set to fine-tune a neural net for identification as a research project. Having 5-10 individuals is more than enough. So far, I've been trying with downloading celebrity images using different search engines (and [icrawler](https://pypi.org/project/icrawler/)), but most search engines give 60-80 images at best (with bing being the best so far with ca. 120).

Comment: Lots of existing answers with this tag: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faces

Answer (score 1):

Instagram  is a start. Just scrape and use opencv  or similar to identify  faces. Or, manually sort faces.

Instagram is a simple http site that can be crawled recursively. It's a matter of counting the images so tweak it and find a good balance. Nobody is going to take 1000 pictures of the same face so dont expect perfection.